# UnsatisfiedDependencyException when referencing Repository from another module

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

I have a Kotlin Spring Boot application (`com.myapp.webapp.Application`) which uses a Repository bean defined in an external library (`com.myapp.engine.MyRepository`). Such repository is not a `JpaRepository` because I want to avoid JPA in this stage of the project, and only resorting to straight SQL queries, so I'm using `Repository` / `@EnableJdbcRepositories`:

```kotlin
package com.myapp.webapp

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
import org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.EnableJdbcRepositories

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = [
    "com.myapp.webapp",
    "com.myapp.engine",
])
@EnableJdbcRepositories(basePackages = ["com.myapp.engine"])
class MyApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<MyApplication>(*args)
}
```

```kotlin
package com.myapp.engine.repository

import com.myapp.engine.MyType
import org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.Query
import org.springframework.data.repository.Repository
import java.util.*

interface MyRepository: Repository<MyType, Int> {

    @Query("select * from my_type", nativeQuery=true)
    fun findAll(): List<MyType>

}
```

Such service is then `@Autowire`d in `com.myapp.engine.service.MyService`, but autowiring fails because no beans for `MyRepository` are found:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.myapp.engine.service.MyService required a bean of type 'com.myapp.engine.repository.MyRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.webapp.engine.repository.MyRepository' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Reading Spring Data JDBC [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.definition) it looks like this approach should be valid. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I had multiple Repository candidates (because I also had `spring-boot-starter-redis` as a dependency). Removing it, or annotating with `@Table` my entity fixed the issue.